# Initial state undefined in redux connected react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

I have a ReactJs app which uses Redux to manage its store. My state is a complex json whose fileds can change. When i initiate  the reducers, i have to specify the initial state else when accessing it before fetching the content from server, i get 'undefined' error. Following is the example,

```js
//Test.jsx
class Test extends React.Component{
    componentWillMount(){
       fetchContent({
         type: SET_CONTENT
       });
    }
    render(){ 
      return(
       <div> {this.props.header} </div>
      )
    }
    mapStateToProps(state){
       return{
         header: state.reducer1.a.b.c
       }
    }
}
export default (mapStateToProps)(Test);


//reducer1.js
export default function reducer1(state = {}, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CONTENT:
      return Object.assign({}, action.data);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
  
//reducer2.js
export default function reducer2(state = {}, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_SOMETHING_ELSE:
      return Object.assign({}, action.data);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
  
//CombinedReducer.js
export default combinedReducers(Object.assign({}, {reducer1}, {reducer2}))
```

Now when the component initialises for the first time, `state.reducer1.a.b.c` throws undefined because the `fetchContent()` doesnt seems to be called at this point.

So my question is how do i solve this issue? Is specifying the initial state in reducer the only option? like the following,

```js
//reducer1.js
export default function reducer1(state = { a: { b: { c: "somedata"}}}, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CONTENT:
      return Object.assign({}, action.data);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do that, but you can also just update your mapState function to check for the existence of the first key.

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
   return{
     header: state.reducer1.a ? state.reducer1.a.b.c : <div>Loading..</div>
   }
}
```

Also I assume you mean to have `mapStateToProps` outside of the class definition, as it's a function you pass to `connect` and not specific to the component:

```
class C {
  ...
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {}

connect(mapStateToProps)(C)
```

Lastly, are you missing dispatch in your `fetchContent` call? Is this using redux-thunk?

Comment: So the only possible solutions if either lnitialize the state like i did or do null checks for each level of data access from the state!

Yeah, the function was supposed to be outside.Since i wrote this quickly, didnt look into that properly. And yes, fetchContent is a function on my action-creator which internally calls dispatch.

Comment: I'm not sure what your expectations are, for something to do the null checks for you? You really just have two states to check a) predata and b) with data. That's just one null check, not at 'every level of data access'

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you shouldn't store all response data in reducers. Your state hierarchy shouldn't repeat hierarchy of JSON response.

It would me more simpler to store only `c` variable in reducer:

```
//reducer1.js

export default function reducer1(state = { c: undefined }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_CONTENT:
      return Object.assign({}, state, { c: action.data.a.b.c });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Also, you have some mistakes in your code:

- `mapStateToProps` function should be defined outside of class
- Instead of directly calling `fetchContent` function, you should pass it result to dispatch.

```js
// Test.jsx

class Test extends React.Component{
  componentWillMount(){
     dispatch(fetchContent({
       type: SET_CONTENT
     }));
  }

  render() { 
    const { header } = this.props;
    return header ? (
      <div>{header}</div>
    ) : (
      <div>Loading...</div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    header: state.reducer1.c
  }
}

export default (mapStateToProps)(Test);
```

Comment: Does that mean redux-store must only store a simple json? Even if the response from the server is complex, deeply nested json , I should convert them into simple 1-level json before storing them into redux-store?

Also, with regards to code mistakes, it was a typing error :) I meant to have the mapStateToProps outside the class definition and my fetchContent is a function in one of my action-creator which uses dispatch internally :)

Comment: @user3807940, It depends on situation. If you getting deeply nested json from server, consider using `normalizr` package. It used for converting deep nested json to 1-level data.

Comment: Ah cool, have heard about normalizr before but never tried it. Will give it a shout then! Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: You can see it usage in action, in my project - https://github.com/1ven/do